# Javascript: Detect if there is an image in the file reader

Tags: javascript, filereader

Is there a way to see if an image file is in the file reader in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to determine if the file is an image by checking few bytes at the beginning of the stream. You can find the header signature of images easily by googling it.

This is a simple way to detect the image type:

```
 reader.onload = function(e) {
      var buffer = reader.result;
      var int32View = new Int32Array(buffer);
      switch(int32View[0]) {
          case 1196314761: 
              file.verified_type = "image/png";
              break;
          case 944130375:
              file.verified_type = "image/gif";
              break;
          case 544099650:
              file.verified_type = "image/bmp";
              break;
          case -520103681:
              file.verified_type = "image/jpg";
              break;
          default:
                            file.verified_type = "unknown";
              break;
      }
        };
```

You can check few  more bytes to give high accuracy to your results.

Comment: getting an empty int32View for any file type `Int32Array []
​
buffer: ArrayBuffer { byteLength: 0 }
​
byteLength: 0
​
byteOffset: 0
​
length: 0`